# how to load selected partialview in a view in asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, layout

I am working on ASP.NET Mvc project. i have a view similar to image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI6Fa.jpg)

I design right panel in layout. my layout code:

```
       <div class="col-md-3 panel panel-info" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" style="margin-top:8px;">
            <div class="panel-heading">Setting</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="list-group">

                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active text-center">Lists</a>
                    <hr />
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Add Users - Partialview 1</a>

                    <a href="~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AddUser.cshtml" class="list-group-item">Edit Users - Partialview 2</a>

                    <a href="~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_UserList.cshtml" class="list-group-item">User List - Partialview 3</a>

                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Set Password - Partialview 4</a>

                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">User Details - Partialview 5</a>

                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Send Message - Partialview 6</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have several modes in right panel contains : Add,Edit,List and ...
Each mode has a special Partialview. I want, when i click on every mode on right panel, special partialview load in left side. how can i load dynamically partialview in asp mvc?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

First you need to make an action to the controller like this in your view

```
     @{Html.RenderAction("youractionname", "controllername");}
```

and then on controller you need to return partial view like this

```
public ActionResult youractionname()
        {
            return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AddUser.cshtml");
        }
```

by this method your partial view will be loaded in your view.

**Method 2**

You can use ajax to load the partialview without refreshing the browser.

First you need to add a div with some id where you need to load the partial view.

```
  <div id="PartialId"></div>
```

then you need to add the action link (on click of the link partial view will be loaded)

```
<a href="javascript:Details()">Select</a>
```

Your ajax method looks like below

```
<script>
    function Details() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("index", "Home")', // your action method
            method: "POST", // your method
            cache: false,
            data: { }
        }).done(function (result) {
            $('#PartialId').html(result);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Note you need to add u add Unobtrusive-Ajax-jquery script to your project.

You can find this [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/)

Comment: thanks a lot, but i have several partialview. how can i place condition when i click on edit load edit partialview and when i click on adduser load adduser partialview?

Comment: Create all the partial views and load on click how I showed above using ajax

Comment: do i need to create a jquery function for any <a> tag?

Comment: thanks...it works perfect. i create jquery function for any <a> tag and use GET method